# Passing an associative array to an object and calling setter for each element in the array

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

I have created an entity class which I want to now construct by passing an associative array to it.
The goal is to end up with each key in the associative array being prepended with "set_" in order to call the appropriate setter method on each value in the associative array.

```
foreach($array AS $key => $value)
{
    if(is_string($value))
    {
        eval( '$this->set_'.$key.'(\''.$value.'\');' );
    }
    elseif(is_array($value))
    {
        eval( '$this->set_'.$key.'('.$value.');' );
    }
}
```

The above code works for elements in $array where $value is a string or an int, but its not working for arrays.

This approach feels clumsy, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You should always describe the meaning of "doesn't work".

Comment: You should never use eval()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [__set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) magic method and [call_user_func()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php). Here is the one of possible solutions how it can be done in more elegant way:

```
class Entity {

    private $foo;
    private $bar;

    public function __construct(Array $params) {
        foreach($params as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set_' . $key;
            if(is_callable(array($this, $method))) {
                call_user_func(array($this, $method), $value);
            }
        }
    }

    public function set_Foo($value) {
        $this->foo = $value;
    }

    public function set_Bar($value) {
        $this->foo = $value;
    }

}
```

Comment: ...and to make the trio complete also consider curly braces notation.

Answer (score 2):

Eval can be dangerous, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
$Function = "set_$key";
call_user_func_array(array($this, $Function), array($Value));
```

$this is calling itself, since this sounds like its being used within a class.

I'd use array_walk_recursive to fire these all off.

Comment: You're the real MVP.